# Changing of Cursor in CursorAdapter

Tags: android, sqlite, exception, android-cursor

I am trying to change `Cursor` in `CursorAdapter` this way:

```
Cursor newCursor = compiledStatement.getCursor();
startManagingCursor(newCursor);
adapter.changeCursor(newCursor);
```

Unfortunatelly I get this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object:
     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery
```

According to other topics, it should be possible to change content of CursorAdapter without creating new one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the problem. My `CursorAdapter` implements `SectionIndexer`, so I had to owerwrite `changeCursor()` method and reset the `Cursor` for `AlphabetIndexer`.

```
@Override
public void changeCursor(Cursor cursor) {
    mIndexer.setCursor(cursor);
    super.changeCursor(cursor);
}
```

Comment: This fixed my problem, but now the Garbage Collector goes crazy. I work with a very long Cursor and everything is recreating everytime. Any suggest?

Answer (score 2):

`changeCursor()` will close the previous Cursor, which is still managed by the Activity, that is probably the reason you are getting the exception. You might try calling `stopManagingCursor()` on the old cursor before you call `changeCursor()`.

Comment: I had same idea, so I have already tried it and with same result: attempt to re-open an already-closed object.