# Change cursor in cursoradapter

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter

Hi I have Custom cursor adapter , in my cursor i have int value which be always 1 or 0 and in my listview i have button for each listitem when i click on it i want to change image background of button and update database.
for button on click listener i use onclick in my xml and create method in my activity class and there i use this code for changing my cursor after update my db

```
startManagingCursor(cursor);
adapter.changeCursor(cursor);
```

but when i run my app i get this error message

```
android.database.StaleDataException: Attempting to access a closed CursorWindow.Most probable cause: cursor is deactivated prior to calling this method.
```

and of course i see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7245833/changing-of-cursor-in-cursoradapter)   and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17004240/changing-cursor-in-cursoradapter-is-not-properly-updating-list-item-views) questions but i don't get my answer clearly.
in first question i don't get this line

```
mIndexer.setCursor(cursor);
```

what is mindexer is? and second question do not relevance to my problem except title .
thanks for any help.